# AWS Aurora Postgresql backup to S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

We are trying to develop a feature to backup our RDS - preferably a db dump with all data, schemas etc.
Currently, our production db, aurora postgres is completely in AWS. We. saw that AWS supports snapshots, but as we understood, the snapshot are supposed to be used only in AWS (it can be used outside, but we need to modify it). Unfortunately, it took us some time to realise that fact and that's why we are pressured.

We don't want to restrict ourselves only to AWS and that's why we want to be able to restore our data in every Postgresql instance.

Our initial idea was to use Cloudwatch to trigger a daily event to lambda / ec2. Then this lambda / ec2 will dump the data to S3 bucket. Then another event will be triggered to store it in Digitalocean Spaces (equivalent to S3).

Our questions are:

1. As for our approach: We are not sure of ours and honestly we are not sure if it's going to work. What do you think of it?
2. Your recommendations - do you know from experience what'd be the best approach for db dumping from AWS. We read a lot of articles, but for some reason nothing was told about it.

Comment: Do you "only" want to store this dump on Digitalocean or will you be able to restore this dump immediately if necessary? if it's "only" for having a backup in case a disaster recovery, I would prefer keeping everything on AWS and just copy the backup to another AWS account (probably using also another region). If your "productive" account has any problems, you can just restore this backup into this other account, set some security group rules (or prepare them) and you are online again. No need to modify/migrate or manual restore process.

Comment: We want to have the ability to restore our DB state in any Postgresql instance we want and not necessarily in AWS.